# Cron job every second

Tags: server, php, cron

How can I run a PHP script every few seconds in Ubuntu Server? (bonus: How can I run random within the cron script, e.g. every 3 seconds + random(3 seconds) )

Comment: I'd recommend that you first evaluate whether you actually need such short intervals. There's a reason they are discouraged, after all.

Comment: What you are asking to do appears like it's a bad idea - in order to satisfy us that you know what you are doing, could you please give some more information about why you want to do this?  What is your application?

Answer (score 6):

`cron` only runs at intervals of one minute or longer. If you really need, you could create a script of some sort that repeats whatever needs doing in a loop and sleeps for 3 seconds between iterations. But There's likely a better means to whatever ends you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: you mean a minimum

Comment: How would such a script look?

Comment: Something along the lines of `while(true){do_something();sleep(3);}`.

Comment: Which would work, but again OP, this is probably a bad idea - we need to know more about what your application/goal is.